# Batch script to delete all folders except of "Starts with"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory, rmdir

I have a folder with several subfolders. Structure is like:

- C:\foo
- C:\foo\web.foo
- C:\foo\web.bar
- C:\foo\win.foo
- C:\foo\win.bar
- C:\foo\mobile.foo
- C:\foo\mobile.bar

I sometimes wish to delete the folders with its containing files with following batch script:

```bat
rmdir C:\foo /s /q
```

Here it didn't matter that the whole folder C:\foo was deleted completely.

But now I only want to delete only the subfolders of C:\foo with its containing files, which **DO NOT start with "web."**.

Do you have any good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick, note it's a batch file using the current directory:

```cmd
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /AD ^| findstr /V "^web."') do (
   echo rmdir %%D /s /q
)
```

If it's okay remove the `echo` in front of `rmdir`.

The dir command just list directory names because of `/AD` and use a simple name output because of `/B`. To search on the beginning use `findstr` with `/V`. For negation use `^`. Further the pipe symbol needs to be escaped `^|`.

---

If you want a dynamic batch script that uses arguments you can use the following, call it via `batchname.bat "C:\foo" web.` (if it's okay remove the `echo` in front of `rmdir`.):

```cmd
@echo off

set INVARGS=0
if [%1] == [] set "INVARGS=1"
if [%2] == [] set "INVARGS=1"
if %INVARGS% == 1 (
   echo echo %0 ^<directory^> ^<directory_prefix^>
   goto eof
)

set "folder=%1%"
set "prefix=%2%"

pushd "%folder%"
echo List of folders that should be deleted:
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /AD ^| findstr /v "^%prefix%"') do (
   echo "%cd%\%%D"
)
popd

:choice
echo.
set /P "c=Are you sure you want to continue [Y/N]?"
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto yes
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto eof
goto :choice

:yes
echo.
pushd "%folder%"
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /AD ^| findstr /v "^%prefix%"') do (
   echo rmdir %%D /s /q
)
popd

:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all files begin with `web.`

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%F in ('dir /b /s') do (
    set "name=%%~nF"
    if /i not "!name:~0,4!" == "web." (
        rm !name!
    )
)
```